# Rails link_to method with turbolinks disables formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, turbolinks

I am formatting videos with video_js gem. For example here how I print my videos:

```
.row
  - @streams.each do |stream|
    = videojs_rails sources: { mp4: stream.video}, setup: "{}", controls: true, width:"400", class: "col-md-10 col-md-offset-1"
```

Everything works fine as expected if I go to that page with a link. If I create button with `link_to` to that page, formatting gets disabled. I need to refresh page to make it look as expected. What's wrong with that? Any ideas?

Comment: it's an issue related to `gem turbolinks` probably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove turbolinks gem from your Gemfile
2. Run bundle install
3. In app/views/layouts/application.html.haml set turbolinks to `false` like that:

`= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => false`

`= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => false`

or remove them.

4. Restart server

Comment: It's easier just to remove the turbolinks declarations in the _tag calls rather than setting them to false.

Comment: Thanks, edited :) First I suggested to set as false, because it is easier to bring'em back if someone would like to bring turbolinks back.

Comment: Bring them back. Why would anyone want to do that? :)

Comment: @weezing it did not help me :/

Comment: @TitasKurtinaitis Try remove //= require turbolinks from  app/assets/javascripts/application.js

Comment: @weezing yeah that helped, removing //= require turbolinks

Comment: @weezing but it is bad answer actually because turbolinks are imported and very fast way to load pages. There is way better answer which i found. :)